# Sphinx, вывод результата

Tags: php, sphinx

Знатоки, доброго времени суток!

Помогите разобраться со сфинксом, так как прочитав кучу мануалов так и не смог понять одну вещь.

Я настроил сфинкс. Он работает и ищет что нужно. Но возвращает только id документа. А я хочу еще возвращать и некоторые поля. Но как добавить их в массив вывода - не могу понять. Кому не сложно - объясните суть. При выводе пользуюсь SphinxQL и библиотекой foolz.

Вот конфигурация:

```
source article
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        =
    sql_db      = parser
    sql_port        = 

    sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8

    sql_query       = \
        SELECT article_id, description, link \
        FROM tb_articles         

        sql_attr_uint    = article_id
}

index article
{
    source            = article 
    path              = C:/openserver/domains/parser/data/article/
    morphology        = stem_ru
    min_word_len        = 1
}

index article_rt
{
    type            = rt
    rt_mem_limit        = 128M
    path            = C:/openserver/domains/parser/data/article_rt/
    rt_field        = article_id
    rt_field        = description
    rt_field        = link
    rt_attr_uint        = article_id
}

searchd
{
    listen         = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
    log            = C:\Sphinx/data/log/searchd.log
    query_log        = C:\Sphinx/data/log/query.log
    pid_file        = C:\Sphinx/data/log/searchd.pid
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно добавить атрибуты `sql_attr` и не забыть их выбрать в запросе `SELECT`.
Вообще они используются для фильтрации или сортировки результатов, но как вариант, конечно, можно их из сфинкса получать.